# Check values in a text file

Tags: awk

Is there a simple way to check if values in the second column of a file ( File 2) exist in the second column of another file (File 1), for example by printing a star next to the concerned line? If possible using awk.

File 1

```
A   1,2,3,4 
B   15,16,17
```

File 2

```
A   3
B   18
```

Expected output: File 3

```
A   1,2,3,4     *
B   15,16,17
```

**EDIT**
What if File 2 looks like:

```
A    3,8
B    18,19
```

but the expected output remains the same?

Comment: Try my updated, fixed possible bug if file1 has `13` and file2 has `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk '
   FNR == NR {
       a[$1] = $2;next
   }
   {
       split(a[$1],b,",");
       for (i in b) {
           if ($2 == b[i]) {
               printf("%s %s\t*\n",$1,a[$1]);
               next;
           }
       }
       print $1,a[$1];
   }
' file1 file2 
A 1,2,3,4   *
B 15,16,17
```

**Update**

With your new input, try:

```
$ awk '
    FNR == NR {
        a[$1] = $2;
        next;
    }
    {
        split($2,b,",");
        split(a[$1],c,",");
        for (i in b) {
            if (b[i] in c) {
                printf("%s %s\t*\n",$1,a[$1]);next;
            }}
                print $1, a[$1];
     }
' file1 file2
```